# How to use the same npm package I'm developing in its own github docs (page)

Tags: github, npm

I'm developing an npm package and I have it on github. I want to use this package on its own github page. I tried installing its tarball (using npm pack) in docs folder but i got this error:

> npm ERR! code ENOSELF. Refusing to install package with name "squanch"
>   under a package also called "squanch". Did you name your project the
>   same

this is my folder structure:

```
-dist
--css
--js
-docs --> i'm trying to install the package here
--index.html
-src
--scss
--js
package.json
gulpfile.js
...
```

Comment: Did you create a new sub package within the docs directory with `npm init` before installning it there? Including adding the docs directory in .npmignore for your top level package

Comment: @jgranstrom no, i did .npmignore thing but the problem was the npm init part, I haven't done that. It's fixed now thanks.

Comment: @NimaHakimi It's good practice to provide an answer to your own question once you've discovered it. I for one would like to know what you ended up doing.